# Clarifying some doubts on the definition of "extensional classes"

Tags: logic, set-theory

On page 68 of Jech's "Set Theory" 4th Edition there is the following definition :

> A class $\mathcal{M}$ is *extensional* if the relation $\in$ on $\mathcal{M}$ is extensional, i.e.,
>   if for any distinct $X$ and $Y \in \mathcal{M}$, $X \cap \mathcal{M}\neq Y \cap \mathcal{M}$.

It makes me think : what does it mean to be distinct in this context ?

If $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of the axiom of extensionality then any two elements of $\mathcal{M}$ are distinct if and only if one of them contain an element that the other does not.

But this cannon't apply here since the whole point of this definition, it seems to me, is to give a criteria for a class to satisfy the axiom of extensionality. Therefore we can't rely on it to define the concept of "distinctness" in $\mathcal{M}$.

Does this mean that $X$ and $Y$ should be direct from the point of view of some transitive class containing $\mathcal{M}$ like the class of well-founded sets ?

If that is the case would it be correct to say that two people (one in the class of well-founded set, and one in an extensional subclass $\mathcal{M}$) always agree on which elements of $\mathcal{M}$ are distinct and which are not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example of a class that is *not* extensional would be
$$\mathcal M = \{\{41,42\},\{42\}\}$$

The elements $\{41,42\}$ and $\{42\}$ are *not the same member of $\mathcal M$* because one of them contains $41$ and the other doesn't. We can see this easily when looking at $\mathcal M$ "from the outside" -- it's just some odd class (even a set).

However the relation $\in$ *restricted to $\mathcal M$* is the empty relation. We have that $\{41,42\}$ and $\{42\}$ are both empty sets *relative to $\mathcal M$*. Someone whose entire world consists of the elements of $\mathcal M$ and the $\in$ relation will not be able to distinguish the two elements.

In other words we have $\{41,42\}\cap\mathcal M = \{42\}\cap\mathcal M = \varnothing$, so our $\mathcal M$ is not extensional.

Comment: But when you say that $\{41, 42\}$ and $\{42\}$ are not the same member of $\mathcal{M}$, you are taking from an external point of view, right ? The "distinctness" is decided from outside of $\mathcal{M}$, right ?

Comment: @M.G: Yes, of course. It's determined in _our_ world, the one where we constructed $\mathcal M$ in the first place. That is the world in which the definition of "extensional" lives.

Comment: Good, that clarify my doubts. Thank you.

Comment: @M.G: The point to remember here is that equality is built into the logic. So the model (or class, here) always knows when two things are not equal. Extensionality means that $\in$ can identify inequality.